# WPF - Drag & dropping multiple items within a ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, listbox

I have a ListBox that implements drag & drop: it works for single items (selecting an item then dragging it on top of another will put it in the right spot), but when selecting multiple items (using shift or ctrl) I have not been able to make it work.

My main issue is I don't know how the `DragDrop.DoDragDrop` function handles batches of items. It works for single items (specify the FrameworkElement, then the data format and the data, finally the drag effects). But if I have multiple items how do I use `DoDragDrop`? Since I have to specify a format wouldn't it always expect a single instance of that format? I have several 'Entities' I want to drag and drop, how do I tell `DragDrop.DoDragDrop` to accept all that data in one operation?

It works perfectly when I am passing just one `DataObject` to the `DoDragDrop` method, but I need to find a way to pass multiple objects in one call.

So far I've tried creating multiple DataObjects and tried creating an array or list to add to `DoDragDrop` as its data but that doesn't work. I also tried looping `DoDragDrop` so it gets called once for every item I'm dragging and that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to solve the issue. For the data I passed a list of objects that I needed to drag, and when handling the drop I would receive the data as a list then do what I needed to do.

The problem I was having was that I couldn't wrap my head around the concept of a "format" not belonging to just one data object. For the format I simply put

`DragDrop.DoDragDrop((FrameworkElement)sender, new DataObject("System.Collections.Generic.List<object>", _dragSources.Select(x => x.DataContext).ToList()), DragDropEffects.Copy);`

and everything worked out. Even in the MSDN documentation it is mentioned nowhere that the "format" part is really just a key. You can put literally anything and as long as it matches what you are using to get the data (in this case `e.Data.GetData("System.Collections.Generic.List<object>") as List<object>;`) then you're golden.